# How to 'refresh' apc cache at high traffic application?

Tags: mysql, symfony, caching, database-performance, apc

My symfony application has ~500 users online, and some article list is available on all pages. I store query and result in APC, which is manually deleted by administrator on some data change. Here is the problem:

If i am correct if every of my 500 users refresh the page when cache is deleted and try to renew it (by first query to the database) other 499 are harming the database before the cache is done.

How to avoid this situation? Is there any option in APC that prevents from it, or i need to manage it manually? The best option should be to serve old cache if new is not ready yet.

Comment: what kind of data do you cache? it is common for all users or it is personal for every user?

Comment: @MaxP. Common for all users

Comment: Possibly a non-problem.  Probably one user will get it refreshed before the second user asks for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm afraid there is no solution out of the box.
If you look at Memcached Bundle they implement a solution to avoid this problem: [enter link description here](https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswMemcacheBundle#adp-anti-dog-pile)

Maybe you can inspire to write your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

If common for all users you can prepare data for cache by background script and execute it by cron. Also it is possible to add version to cache keys for this data, store version in apc too. On preparing data for cache, increment version and save new data with new version, than change version in apc.